# NotImplemented Attribute C#

Tags: c#, exception, attributes

A simple question: Why there isn't any NotImplementedAttribute in C#?

You can always throw the exception, but I think it would be nice for this to work as the 
ObsoleteAttribute -> you get an warning for using that method.

Ok, you have a method with this attribute, and when you implement it you have to remove the attribute by hand, but I think this is safer than using methods with throw new NotImplementedException() inside...and wait for them to get called.

I remember reading that the Obsolete is hard coded into the compiler, but maybe there is some spare room for this one :)

This is just my opinion, maybe I am wrong. But it's something that I would like to see.

Thanks

Comment: good suggestion to use this attribute to hide the inner implementation.

Comment: Not constructive. Ask this question Microsoft.

Comment: Bit of a chicken-and-egg problem isn't it?  You'd actually have to implement *something* to give it the attribute.  Using /* */ works just as well.

Comment: Possibly raise this with visualstudio.uservoice.com - http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio.

Comment: @Hans Passant - Yes, agree with you. But a compiler warning is observed faster than the documentation of a method.

Comment: NotImplementedException is designed to be replaced with actual runable code. It's a placeholder. I think you're thinking of NotSupportedException, which is designed to allow sub-classes to specify that they don't support certain aspects of their base class or interface and since those are likely to be called through their base class or interface you won't know about it until run time at which point the compiler can't help you. But NotImplementedException is there to make sure that you don't forget to implement a method when it was added for you by the tools (as opposed to adding it yourself).

Comment: @Orion Adrian - No, that's exactly what I want. Code that was generated automatically, to force me somehow to know that I am using code that has no implementation at compile time, not at runtime as it is now.

Comment: There is a better implementation of what you are describing... `abstract`

Comment: @AndreiNeagu  Ok, I understand what you're getting at now. Ultimately you would still need to throw NotImplementedException because they're not going to break compatibility at this point. The attribute therefore becomes unnecessary as you can simply look for the pattern in compiled code. I'm fairly certain some analysis tools already do this. Ultimately the VS team could do it too, but I'm fairly certain they have other projects with higher priority. They tend to leave code analysis stuff like this to 3rd-parties or FxCop.

Comment: Abstract method declarations are only permitted in abstract classes. I usually find that `NotImplementedException`s are used in concrete classes (for inherited methods that are not ever meant to be used, or as a place holder for future code). In both cases a compiler error will give faster feedback to the programmer. As I understand (and I may be wrong), FxCop has to be run separately and in many companies is only done during code review. [Please Support](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2901480-making-a-notimplementedattribute-that-would-give-a).

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually, that's not what he is describing.  With proper IoC and dependency injection you'll see abstract classes being referenced all over the place, since the concrete classes will be called during runtime.  He is looking for intellisense to tell the client coder that "this class is not done - do not call it".

Comment: I don't understand why this hasn't been implemented already!
Scenario (why I would like a NotImplemented attribute): I know in the future, a table in my code first entity framework will require support for an additional field.  I want the field included in the next migration so that I don't have migrate the database twice but I don't want the field to be used until I have finished the development required by that field (and so I'd appreciate warnings earlier than runtime exceptions).